# How to convert a specific function to a udf function in apache spark with scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a data frame in apache spark, created using Scala. This data frame has two columns of type Array[String]. I have written a simple function which takes those two columns and returns the intersection of words (return number of common words: Int). 
One example of my data frame is shown below.

[data frame example with its columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8WYQ.png)

The function is the follow one:

```
def findNumberCommonWordsTitle(string1:Array[String], string2:Array[String]) ={
val intersection = string1.intersect(string2)
intersection.length  }
```

I want to convert this function to udf function. I have tried this:

```
val fncwt=udf(findNumberCommonWordsTitle(_:Array[String],_:Array[String]))

finalDF.select(fncwt(finalDF("title_from_words"),finalDF("title_to_words"))).show(5)
```

but I am getting an error as bellow:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFudX.png)

The error message says: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

What I am doing wrong? I think that the problem is a type mismatch but I am not sure.

After that, I want to create a new **column** on my data frame with the returned values of the function above.

How can I achieve that? What should I do to fix the error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should be

```
def findNumberCommonWordsTitle(string1: Seq[String], string2: Seq[String]) ={
   ...
}
```

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types

Comment: I have made this modification on my code but still I am getting an error!  

This time something defferent:  

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (array<string>) => array<string>) But my function now is this : def findNumberCommonWordsTitle(title_from:Seq[String], title_to:Seq[String]) ={ val intersection = title_from.intersect(title_to) intersection.length }

Comment: Finally, I realized that the problem caused when I call dataframe.show()  When I call .show() with an integger attribute e.g. 2, the program excecuted.  I cant understand why is this happening.

Comment: Every time I call .show() with a number > 2 the program fails!